# Keep div vertically centered to visible part of parent element

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

Currently I have a header element with the following code

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
            <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="align-self: center">
                <h1>My header</h1>
                <span id="slogan">my slogan</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

The header element starts at the beginning of body and ends 75 px short of the window bottom.

```
header {
    height: calc(100vh - 75px);
}
```

When I start scrolling downwards, the header element starts moving up with the header and the slogan span. However, I want to keep the `h1` and `span` elements vertically centered to the visible part of the header element, somewhat like on the [iStockPhoto website](http://www.istockphoto.com/). Notice how you scroll down the search form stays vertically centered to the background image container.

How do I implement something similar?

Comment: are you referring to the parralax effect or what? your question is unclear..

Comment: that's a script to set fixed position and move the top val ... use the inspector tools

Answer (score 0):

After a little bit of trial and error I created the effect with the following code.

```
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="display: flex; justify-content: center">
      <div class="col-xs-12 text-center" style="align-self: center">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <span id="slogan">my slogan</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<section style="height: 1000px">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

```
$(function() {
    var initialTitleHeight = $("header h1").position().top,
        initialSloganBottom = $("header span").position().top + $("header span").height(),
        headerHeight = $("header").height(),
        headerMaxMargin = headerHeight - (initialSloganBottom - initialTitleHeight + 50);

    $(window).scroll(function(event) {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop(),
            marginTop = (initialTitleHeight + scroll < headerMaxMargin) ? initialTitleHeight + scroll : headerMaxMargin;

        $("header h1").css({
            marginTop: marginTop + "px"
        });
    });
})
```

```
header {
    height: calc(100vh - 75px);
    background-color: #F90;

    .container, .row {
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

You can try it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2nz6zqea/1/).